# Intel X25M 80GB SSD vs. OCZ RevoDrive 50GB SSD

Tags: ssd

I already have 4 X25M 80GB drives in RAID. I was just wondering by looking at the specs of OCZ's RevoDrive 50GB SSD if there is noticable difference between the two drives and if I should consider upgrading to the 50GB. I'm just running system on the drives to get maximum speed so the size is irrelevant. Price/speed is the main factor.

Does anyone have expreriance with RevoDrive SSDs?

Comment: You have *4* X-25M 80GB's and *price* is a factor now? :)

Comment: What is the RodeoDrive? Did you mean *Revo* Drive?

Comment: Well if you have 4 drive and each is $200 and you have another set of 4 drives which is $300 that makes $400 difference. And that is a BIG factor. There is no shame wanting to save even on more powerful drives. Obviously you don't sell high-end custom boxes otherwise you would not ask this.

Comment: Typo fixed; http://www.ocztechnology.com/products/solid-state-drives/pci-express/revodrive/ocz-revodrive-pci-express-ssd-.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The windows start up is only a little bit faster (like 1 sec).  The rest is pretty much the same during interface.  Only exception is when copying over BIG files (like 20 GB or more).  You'll notice a few second differences here too.  Other than that, I personally would not pay the extra money for a RevoDrive over my Intel X25.  If I was in your shoes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'll say if you want an SSD I haven't heard much bad about Intel. On the other hand, I've seen OCZ have after market soldiering on the RevoDrive. Besides this I've owned an OCZ drive and it broke. After much research I found the quality of OCZ SSD's to be extremely questionable.

Also remember you get the Intel 510, which replaces previous models. And the RevoDrive doesn't support trim, because it comes in RAID 0 configuration OOB.

EDIT: pick up a new mobo, and a PCI raid controller, and buy 2x Intel 510's and you'll be smiling.